# How to use ng-repeat for nested JSON to bind key values

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

How to use ng-repeat to bind key values in the following JSON?

For example I want to display the value of Peacefulness tools for life.
and then on their click want to display their subobjects data in next page.

```js
var meditationData = {
    "Peacefulness": {
        "Breathing": {
            "fivemin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…",
            "threemin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…",
            "description": "Some description Some description Some description Some description…",
            "tenmin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…"
        },
        "Rest": {
            "fivemin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…",
            "threemin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…",
            "description": "Some description Some description Some description Some description…",
            "tenmin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…"
        }
    },
    "Tools For Life": {
        "Abundance": {
            "fivemin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…",
            "threemin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…",
            "description": "Some description Some description Some description Some description…",
            "tenmin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…"
        },
        "Patience": {
            "fivemin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…",
            "threemin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…",
            "description": "Some description Some description Some description Some description…",
            "tenmin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…"
        },
        "Kidness": {
            "fivemin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…",
            "threemin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…",
            "description": "Some description Some description Some description Some description…",
            "tenmin": "http://s1281.ve.vc/data/128/35750/276391/Shoon_Shaan_(iTunes)_-_Dil…"
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Your code is missing.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I've been looking for some HTML.

Comment: its Ok. I just want to know how to use ng-repeat in this kind of JSON

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-repeat="(key, value) in data"` like

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in meditationData">
    <a href="#" ng-click="view(key)">{{key}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:**
See [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0uq58frs/2/)

Comment: thanks for reply, but it's giving an error meditationData can't find variable

Comment: bro can u help me again ?

Comment: on click i am only getting key value. but i want to get whole data inside that key ?? plz help

Comment: The ng-click triggers the method `view(key)` with the selected key as a parameter. You could then transition to a new state or show a modal with the data. `$scope.view = function(key) { console.log($scope.meditationData[key]); }` logs the data to console.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```
<select ng-model="values" ng-options="value as key for (key,value) in meditationData"></select>
```

Don´t forget the ng-model so you will store the object value selected

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20166/)

**EDIT:**

For getting the value for the key is easy

```
<select ng-change="change()" ng-model="values" ng-options="value as key for (key,value) in meditationData">
```

and on controller

```
$scope.change = function(){
    console.log($scope.values);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20324/)

```
<div ng-repeat="x in meditationData">

      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in x">
        {{key}} : {{value}}
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but on click i am only getting key value. but i want to get whole data inside that key ?? plz help

Answer (score 1):

you can repeat through each objects using the ng-repeat="(key,value) in ObjectDefinedInScope"

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key1,value1) in meditationData">
        {{key1}}
         <ul ng-repeat="(key2,value2) in value1" >
            <li>
                {{key2}}
                <ul ng-repeat="(key3,value3) in value2" >
                    <li>{{key3}} : {{value3}}</li>
                </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

[jsfiddle solution to your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/daslusan/rb7cn92t/)

Note: This is the beauty of AngularJS, it helps you extend HTML into a more expressive and readable format

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the keys of `meditationData` in a array, to do so use the following line:

```
Object.keys(meditationData);
```

The above code returns an array like this: ["Peacefulness", "Tools For Life"]

With the help of returned array you can do `ng-repeat` in template.
In ng-click function get the clicked key as a parameter and based on the received value show the corresponding data.

Comment: No need to get keys, since he could use `ng-repeat="(key, value) in data"`. Creating an array only for the keys would be overhead.